# How to prevent cursor from getting stuck in css transform:rotate in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In this code I'm trying to allow the user to grab the black square and rotate it around the inner circle.

http://jsfiddle.net/4CL9H/1/

If you try to do this, you'll notice that the cursor gets stuck about 50% of the time in firefox, preventing the `$(document).off('mousemove');` from executing unless you click again to call the `mouseup` event hanlder.

This seems to work fine in IE, chrome and safari (crashes if you rapidly click the black square) however it's giving me problems in firefox.

Is there anyway I can improve this code so that the cursor doesn't get stuck in firefox?

**NOTE**
If you're having trouble getting the cursor to get stuck, try clicking and holding (without moving) a bottom corner of the black box and then quickly moving the cursor left to right.

Comment: It does not get stuck in Google Chrome.

Comment: Yes I know... I mentioned it only gets stuck in firefox *This seems to work fine in IE, chrome and safari*

Comment: I think it is because of the dragging.

Comment: Its working fine in FF11

Comment: @LedZeppelin - A question here: What if the cursor is at the very middle of the circle, then will it breaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add event.preventDefault in the mousedown section.

```
$('#container').on('mousedown', '#marker', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(document).on('mousemove', function(event){
        rotateAroundCircle($('#innerCircle').parent(), event.pageX,event.pageY, $('#marker'));
    });
});
```

I modified your fiddle accordingly and did corner testing. Seemed to work fine. [New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CL9H/5/)